# How to fix a broken icon on an android phone

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, launcher

The icon is displayed as a grey icon name "Text Info" and an image of a small SD card on the bottom right of the the icon; when I try to launch it, it says:

> Application not installed.

[image]

Have check Google Play store of installed app but not found.

Listing installed package

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
shell@android:/ $ pm list packages -u
pm list packages -u
package:air.com.sarahnorthway.rebuild2
package:android
package:android.googleSearch.googleSearchWidget
package:br.com.beholdstudios.knightspp
package:ccc71.bmw.pro
package:com.IOIO.cs
package:com.akvelon.signaltracker
package:com.android.MtpApplication
package:com.android.Preconfig
package:com.android.backupconfirm
package:com.android.bluetooth
package:com.android.browser
package:com.android.calendar
package:com.android.certinstaller
package:com.android.chrome
package:com.android.clipboardsaveservice
package:com.android.contacts
package:com.android.defcontainer
package:com.android.email
package:com.android.exchange
package:com.android.htmlviewer
package:com.android.keychain
package:com.android.mms
package:com.android.musicfx
package:com.android.noisefield
package:com.android.packageinstaller
package:com.android.phasebeam
package:com.android.phone
package:com.android.pickuptutorial
package:com.android.providers.applications
package:com.android.providers.calendar
package:com.android.providers.contacts
package:com.android.providers.downloads
package:com.android.providers.downloads.ui
package:com.android.providers.drm
package:com.android.providers.media
package:com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks
package:com.android.providers.security
package:com.android.providers.settings
package:com.android.providers.telephony
package:com.android.providers.userdictionary
package:com.android.server.device.enterprise
package:com.android.server.vpn.enterprise
package:com.android.settings
package:com.android.settings.mt
package:com.android.sharedstoragebackup
package:com.android.smspush
package:com.android.stk
package:com.android.systemui
package:com.android.vending
package:com.android.vpndialogs
package:com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
package:com.dropbox.android
package:com.facebook.katana
package:com.google.android.apps.authenticator2
package:com.google.android.apps.docs
package:com.google.android.apps.maps
package:com.google.android.apps.plus
package:com.google.android.apps.uploader
package:com.google.android.backup
package:com.google.android.calendar
package:com.google.android.feedback
package:com.google.android.gm
package:com.google.android.gms
package:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
package:com.google.android.gsf
package:com.google.android.gsf.login
package:com.google.android.location
package:com.google.android.maps.mytracks
package:com.google.android.marvin.talkback
package:com.google.android.partnersetup
package:com.google.android.setupwizard
package:com.google.android.street
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.bookmarks
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar
package:com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
package:com.google.android.talk
package:com.google.android.tts
package:com.google.android.voicesearch
package:com.google.android.youtube
package:com.google.zxing.client.android
package:com.hangseng.servicemenuapp
package:com.infraware.polarisviewer4
package:com.lifevibes.trimapp
package:com.monotype.android.font.shaonv
package:com.ookla.oftaperformancetest
package:com.osp.app.signin
package:com.pccw.pccwHotspotFinder_Tourist
package:com.playstation.psstore
package:com.samsung.SMT
package:com.samsung.android.app.divx
package:com.samsung.android.livewallpaper.deepsea
package:com.samsung.app.playreadyui
package:com.samsung.avrcp
package:com.samsung.inputmethod
package:com.samsung.map
package:com.samsung.scloud.scloudstarter
package:com.samsung.scrc.idi.server
package:com.samsung.sec.android.application.csc
package:com.samsung.shareshot
package:com.sec.android.Kies
package:com.sec.android.allshare.framework
package:com.sec.android.app.DataCreate
package:com.sec.android.app.FileShareClient
package:com.sec.android.app.FileShareServer
package:com.sec.android.app.SecSetupWizard
package:com.sec.android.app.bluetoothtest
package:com.sec.android.app.camera
package:com.sec.android.app.clockpackage
package:com.sec.android.app.controlpanel
package:com.sec.android.app.factorymode
package:com.sec.android.app.fm
package:com.sec.android.app.gamehub
package:com.sec.android.app.kieswifi
package:com.sec.android.app.launcher
package:com.sec.android.app.lcdtest
package:com.sec.android.app.memo
package:com.sec.android.app.minimode.res
package:com.sec.android.app.mobileprint
package:com.sec.android.app.music
package:com.sec.android.app.myfiles
package:com.sec.android.app.personalization
package:com.sec.android.app.phoneutil
package:com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator
package:com.sec.android.app.popupuireceiver
package:com.sec.android.app.samsungapps
package:com.sec.android.app.samsungapps.una2
package:com.sec.android.app.selftestmode
package:com.sec.android.app.servicemodeapp
package:com.sec.android.app.shareapp
package:com.sec.android.app.sns3
package:com.sec.android.app.sysscope
package:com.sec.android.app.twdvfs
package:com.sec.android.app.videoplayer
package:com.sec.android.app.voicerecorder
package:com.sec.android.app.wallpaperchooser
package:com.sec.android.app.wlantest
package:com.sec.android.cloudagent.dropboxoobe
package:com.sec.android.daemonapp.ap.accuweather
package:com.sec.android.drmpopup
package:com.sec.android.dttsupport
package:com.sec.android.fotaclient
package:com.sec.android.gallery3d
package:com.sec.android.inputmethod
package:com.sec.android.motions.settings.panningtutorial
package:com.sec.android.preloadinstaller
package:com.sec.android.provider.badge
package:com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider
package:com.sec.android.providers.downloads
package:com.sec.android.sCloudBackupApp
package:com.sec.android.sCloudBackupProvider
package:com.sec.android.sCloudRelayData
package:com.sec.android.sCloudSync
package:com.sec.android.saslideshow
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.SPlannerAppWidget
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.analogclocksimple
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.analogclockunique
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.hero.accuweather
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.hero.accuweather.widget
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.yahoonews
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.yahoostock.stockclock
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.digitalclock
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.dualclockanalog
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.dualclockdigital
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.memo
package:com.sec.android.widgetapp.webmanual
package:com.sec.app.RilErrorNotifier
package:com.sec.bcservice
package:com.sec.ccl.csp.app.secretwallpaper.themetwo
package:com.sec.chaton
package:com.sec.dsm.phone
package:com.sec.dsm.system
package:com.sec.enterprise.permissions
package:com.sec.factory
package:com.sec.modem.settings
package:com.sec.pcw.device
package:com.sec.phone
package:com.sec.spp.push
package:com.smlds
package:com.studiokuma.callfilter
package:com.whatsapp
package:com.wsomacp
package:com.wssnps
package:com.wssyncmldm
package:de.android.wifioverviewpro
package:jackpal.androidterm
package:jp.co.ponos.battlecats
package:kr.sira.vibration
package:lysesoft.andftp
package:lysesoft.andsmb
package:me.kiip.skeemo
package:org.adblockplus.android
package:org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service
package:org.zwanoo.android.speedtest
shell@android:/ $
```

Gather log file with:

```
adb logcat -s "Launcher"
```

Log file:

```
E/Launcher(  762): Unable to launch. tag=Item(id=71 folderId=-1 screen=-1 cell=-1 title=Text Info componentName=ComponentInfo{com.android.stk/com.android.stk.StkLauncherActivity2} unavailable=true) intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[ xxx ] flg=0x10200000 cmp=xxxx }
E/Launcher(  762): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.stk/com.android.stk.StkLauncherActivity2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1388)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3195)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3302)
E/Launcher(  762):  at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.startActivitySafely(Launcher.java:1735)
E/Launcher(  762):  at com.android.launcher2.MenuAppsGrid$StateNormal$1.run(MenuAppsGrid.java:1084)
E/Launcher(  762):  at com.android.launcher2.PagedView$2.onAnimationRepeat(PagedView.java:1588)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1128)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:551)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:934)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:957)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:370)
E/Launcher(  762):  at com.android.launcher2.PagedView.animateClickFeedback(PagedView.java:1596)
E/Launcher(  762):  at com.android.launcher2.MenuAppsGrid$StateNormal.onClickAppItem(MenuAppsGrid.java:1081)
E/Launcher(  762):  at com.android.launcher2.MenuAppsGrid.onClick(MenuAppsGrid.java:196)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3567)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14224)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/Launcher(  762):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
E/Launcher(  762):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/Launcher(  762):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/Launcher(  762):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
E/Launcher(  762):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
E/Launcher(  762):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I know that you can simply hide the broken icon from display. but the question is: "how to fix it" rather than hiding it.

Answer (score 1):

You or Android moved this app to the SD card, but either you removed the SD card (maybe you replaced it with a different one) or the files on the SD card are corrupt. Either way, you can't run this app until fixing the problem.

If you removed the SD card, replace the card that the app is on. (The icon won't change right away if you do this, but you'll be able to click it to launch the app.) If the SD card is corrupt, you probably need to reinstall the app. It might be possible to recover the file from the SD card but that's probably going to be more work than reinstalling.

Comment: My SD card corrupt. i manage to locate the message in logcat, any more suggestion?

Comment: @AntonyLee As I said, the easiest thing to do in this case is delete and reinstall the app.

Comment: i have no idea what that app is, by the way, how can i delete the app ? I just unable to do it since it is in no where.

Comment: tried adb uninstall com.android.stk, but it simply return failed.

Comment: If it's a microSD card, you could remove it from the phone and attach it to your computer using a card reader. If the computer still can read it, copy all contents to an empty folder on your computer. Then transfer it to a new card, and re-insert that into your Android device. Should the card be unreadable on your computer, you might have to do a fresh start with an empty card; you could simply try to re-install affected apps (which should work), then uninstall those you want to get rid of.

Comment: @Izzy it failed when runnning adb uninstall com.android.stk, how u can uninstall it, when u cannot do it through goole play, nor from command line, and there is nowhere offer this package to install either. I didn't add it manually either, the icon just appear from nowhere somehow. This is a non-rooted phone and there is no point to root for the issues.

Comment: Simple: you cannot. The app you mention is a system app (Sim ToolKit). You didn't install it, neither some other app loaded it -- it's simply part of your ROM.